# Enable all Screen Options by default

Tags: screen-options

I am currently hiding the screen options tab on a post edit screen with this function...

```
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
function remove_screen_options(){
    return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
}
```

This is working well, but if somebody has previously disabled a screen option then it is missing and they have no way of bringing it back.

Is there a way to force all screen options to be checked for all users?

Answer (score 1):

These are only hidden via CSS, so enqueing your own admin CSS via [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) to display them should fix it.

```
body.js.wp-admin.wp-core-ui  #wpbody .hide-if-js {
  display: block;
}
```